# Azure DevOps firstname.lastname login length

Tags: azure-devops

What is the maximum length for `firstname.lastname` combination for login? For example, I am observing that using combination like:
**first name** - `firstname`
**last name** - `lastname1234`
and using `firstname.lastname1234` as user name fails, so I have to truncate it to `firstname.lastname12`
so I wonder, what is the actual limit, or I am having configuration issue.

Comment: Cannot find the sigin option with firstname.lastname, but typically use email for login. Could you please share a screenshot of your login page? And do you use azure devops cloud service or on-prem azure DevOps server(version?)?

Comment: cannot share screenshots, sorry - company policy no screenshots. as far as I understands, this is all in cloud, but yes, also need to truncate email as  firstname.lastname12@mycompany.com, not firstname.lastname1234@mycompany.com.

Comment: Hi @user2109066, there is no such email length limit from DevOps side, the limit could come from azure custom policy or 3-party application. Please check the details in the reply, let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such user email length limit in DevOps. We can even use below long email for login:

[image]

But we do have user email length limit([Username Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#username-policies)) on Azure account:

[image]

If your DevOps account is from Azure active directory account, it should obey above rule on azure.

For the email length limit you encounter, if your DevOps organization is backed to AAD tenant, there could be an Azure custom policy which will enforce specific rules for user email addresses.

Also, you can double check the browser website, make sure it's not directed by 3rd-party applications which could have email address validation.